# locking the screen requires restarting pulseaudio

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio

I'm using my graphics card as the sound output device:

[image]

I noticed that if I lock the screen in such a way that it actually goes blank (the monitor/TV says "no signal") and then unlock it, the audio can switch to "dummy output" and requires

```
$ systemctl --user restart pulseaudio
```

to start working again.

Is there any way to fix this once and for all?

*EDIT:* I tried the suggestion from [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=341554) (editing `/etc/pulse/default.pa`) but it didn't help.